# How stop service with Handler

Tags: java, android

How make Handler stop together Service

Service:

```
int delay = 10000;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        //Do Something every 10 seconds
        new Handler().postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);

...

public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
}
```

In Activity on I call stopService this Handler keep running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your handler in the following way: add a boolean flag which you would set to 'false' when you would need to stop the handler. Inside your runnable, add the following:

```
int delay = 10000;
static boolean running = true;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        if (running) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }
}, delay);

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
    running = false;
}
```

It will simply not start again.

Comment: this is how things are done, instead of running in a `while(true` loop. +1. though, for a bonus cookie, i'd avoid making dozens of handlers and simply reuse the first one. then in stopSelf() simply call `handler.removeMessagesAndCallbacks()` as well as setting `running = false` and be done with it.

Comment: Yep, your suggestion is very right. Most likely it won't post any more messages anyway, but it is good to do just in case.

Comment: gets rid of references to dead threads, which helps memory and prevents slow-downs and keeps it responsive. although, not very applicable if constantly creating/instancing `new Handler`s though.